# Osmdroid vs Mapsforge

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, mapsforge

I will develop a new Android application, in the past I developed an a application and I used Mapsforge, but now I see their web and they havent got release since Mar 2013...

What do you recommend me to use, Osmdroid or Mapsforge?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapsforge 0.4.0 will release in the next couple of weeks: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/jVXHLgPz7cA also the mailing list traffic is healthy again IMO. So go for Mapsforge if it fullfills your other requirements.

Comment: Surfing the web I have found https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/ and it looks preaty good, what do you think abour this??

Comment: It is not offline I think

Comment: When will be release the version 0.4.0?

Comment: you should ask this on the mailing list